# What is the most efficient way to send a binary websocket message?

Tags: binary, websocket, netty

I have already created a MessageToMessageCodec implementation to go to/from BinaryWebSocketFrame and our own POJO.  This works well, but I don't know that it's optimal.

Since our POJO supports direct codec to/from byte[], is there a more efficient way to send/receive a byte[] over a netty websocket?  Can I just call Channel.writeAndFlush(byte[]) and the underlying websocket handler code will put this into a BinaryWebSocketFrame automatically - and, if so, would this be more efficient than constructing the BinaryWebSocketFrame in my own codec?

Just looking for the most efficient approach to sending/receiving the message.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to construct a new BinaryWebSocketFrame by your own. This is the way to go.

Comment: This is what we're doing in our codec, so it sounds like we're doing this as efficiently as we can.  Thanks, Norman